# Prevent blog posts from covering footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On our blog page, the posts keep covering up the footer and making things quite ugly. I feel like this is probably going to require a little bit of code editing on my part but I'm not sure where to look. Would someone please take a gander and let me know if there are any quick-fixes? I have searched but can't find anything that covers this problem.

Thank you so much!!!

For others - I'm using the Metamorphosis theme. Code follows (Style.css).

```
/*  
Theme Name: Meta-Morphosis
Version: 1.5.0
Description: Designed by <a href="http://www.woothemes.com">WooThemes</a>.
Author: WooThemes
Author URI: http://www.woothemes.com

Copyright: (c) 2009 WooThemes.
License: GNU General Public License v2.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

*/

/* The following was added to hide the underlines for links. Ask Audrey and Anna if they like it this way */
a:link {text-decoration:none;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {text-decoration:none;} /* visited link */
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {text-decoration:underline;}  /* selected link */

/*Add Nevis font*/
@font-face{
font-family:nevis;
src:url('/www/wp-content/themes/metamorphosis/Fonts/nevis.ttf') format ("truetype");
}

/* Default styles */
@import "reset.css";

body {
    background:#fff url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/background.jpg") repeat-x top left;
    width: 100%;
    height:38px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    /*

  OLD CODE

  background:#fcfded url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;

  */

}
p{ text-align:justify; color:#666; line-height:26px; }

#wrap { 
    background: none; 
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

/* Wrap */

#wrap { }

/* Top */

#top {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;   
  height:119px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}

/* Page Nav */

#nav_menu {width: 100%; text-align:center;

}

#pagenav li a:link, #pagenav li a:visited {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#pagenav li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

#pagenav li a:hover, #pagenav li.current_page_item a:link, #pagenav li.current_page_item a:visited  {
    position: relative;
}

#pagenav li a:hover span.left, #pagenav li.current_page_item span.left  {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-left:-10px;
}

#pagenav li a:hover span.right, #pagenav li.current_page_item span.right  {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;   
    bottom: 0;
    width: 5px; 
    height: 0px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}

#pagenav li a:link, #pagenav li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

#pagenav li a:hover, #pagenav li.current_page_item a:link, #pagenav li.current_page_item a:visited  {
    background: url(images/top-nav-tile.png) repeat-x left bottom;
}

#pagenav li a:hover span.left, #pagenav li.current_page_item span.left  {
    background: url(images/top-nav-left.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}

#pagenav li a:hover span.right, #pagenav li.current_page_item span.right  {
    background: url(images/top-nav-right.png) no-repeat left bottom !important;
}
#contact {
  left: 827px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 64px;
  width: 100px;
}
/* Cat Nav */

#menu { 
    background:#fff url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/nav.jpg")no-repeat top left;
    width:960px;
    height:33px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}

#catnav, #catnav ul {
    padding: 10;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    list-style: none; 
    line-height: 1;
    width:960px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 8px;
}

#catnav a {
/*  margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    z-index: 100;
    color:#0d1261;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 18px; */
   border-left: 1px solid #5B8492;
  color: #5B8492;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#catnav li {
    float: left;
}
#catnav li:hover {
    background:none;
}

/* Style drop down list */

#catnav li ul { position: absolute; width: 182px; left: -999em; margin:0; }
#catnav li ul li {  border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width:0 1px 1px; background: #FFF; z-index: 15; position: relative; }
#catnav li ul li:hover { background: #eee; }
#catnav li ul li a { line-height: 35px; font-size: 12px; color: #333; width: 160px; }
#catnav li ul ul {  margin: -36px 0 0 180px;  border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#catnav li ul ul li a { line-height: 35px; }
#catnav li ul li ul li a {  border-width:0 1px 1px 0px; }
#catnav li:hover ul, #catnav li.sfhover ul { left: auto; }
#catnav li:hover ul ul, #catnav li.sfhover ul ul { left: -999em; }
#catnav li:hover ul, #catnav li li:hover ul, #catnav li.sfhover ul, #catnav li li.sfhover ul { left: auto; }
#catnav li:hover, #catnav li.hover { position: static; border-bottom: 5px solid #22B0ED; } /* IE7 Fix */

/* Search */

#search { position:absolute; right:20px; top:10px; width: 178px; height:32px; display:block; }
#search input { 
    background:url(images/bg-search.jpg) no-repeat; 
    border:0; 
    color:#fff;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width:157px;
}

/* Header */

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
    padding: 0px 0;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;

}

/*#header a { width:500px; height:100px; display:block; }*/
#header .logoheader { width:500px; height:141px; display:block; }
#header h1 { position:absolute; left:-999em; }
#header .social { position:absolute; left:802px; top: 20px; }

/* Content */
.dental_content .dental-textnew {   float: left;  width: 870px; }
.dental-content .dental-textnew p {  color: #666666;  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size: 14px;  line-height: 200%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;}
#content {
    background:#fff url(images/bg-content.png) repeat-y right;
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height: 550px;
    padding: 0;
}
* html #content { height: 550px; }
#content-bot { background:url(images/bg-content-footer.png) no-repeat; width:960px; height:18px; margin:0 auto; display:block; }


#content.white { background:#fff; }

#featured { padding:20px 0px 0px 20px;  width:440px; }
#main { padding:10px 20px 0px 0; width:425px; }
#main-full {  padding: 1px 0 0;  width: 965px;}


/* Content (style) */

#content a { text-decoration: none; }
#content a:hover {  text-decoration: underline; }
#content h2, #content h3 { font-weight: bold; }
#content h2 { font-size: 24px; line-height:28px; padding-top:0; }
#content h3 {font-size: 20px; }
#content h3.info { font-size:28px; color: #222; padding:0 0 15px; }
#content h4 { font-size: 16px; }
#content ol, #content ul { line-height: 18px; }
#content ul { padding-left: 50px; }
#content ul li { list-style: circle; padding: 3px 0; line-height:16px; font-size:12px; }
#content ol { padding-left: 57px; }
#content ol li { list-style: decimal; padding: 3px 0; }
#content blockquote {
    border-left:2px solid #777777;
    color:#777777;
    font-style:italic;
    margin:5px auto 15px;
    padding:0px 10px;
    width:85%;
}

/* Main Content (post) */

#content .post { padding:0px 0px 15px 0px; }
#content .post-title {  width: 100%; position: relative; }
#content .post-title h2, #content .post-title p.post-details, #content .post-title h3 { padding-right: 50px; }
#content h2 a, #content h3 a { color: #2A2A2A; text-decoration: none; }
#content h2 a:hover, #content h3 a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
#content p.post-details { line-height: 18px; margin-top: -10px; position: relative; }
#content p.post-details a { text-decoration: underline; color:#9F9F9F; }
#content p.post-details a:hover { color:#555; }
#content p.post-details {
    color: #9F9F9F;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0 0px 0px 1px
}
#content .post h4 { margin-top: 1px; clear: both; width: 100%; }
#content .post h4.continue a {
    background: #A8BC70;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content .post h4.continue a:hover {background: #9fb26a;}
#content .post img.thumbnail {
    border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin:5px 0 0;
}
#content .post img.thumbnail-left {
    margin:15px 10px 5px 0;
    float:left;
}
#content .post img.gallery { margin:0 7px 7px 0; }
#content h2.arh {
    border-bottom: #EBEBEB 1px solid;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#featured h2 { font-size:34px; }

#featured .block { padding:0 30px 20px 0px; width:200px; float:left; }
#featured .block.last { padding-right:0px; }
#featured .block h2 { font-size:18px; line-height:20px; font-weight:normal }



/* Main Content (post>single) */

#content p.tags {
    background:url(images/ico-tag.gif) no-repeat center left;
    padding-left:25px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
.single #content .advert_468x60 {margin: 15px 0 0px 0;}
#content .page h2 {padding-top: 5px;}

#page-outline-dental {
  background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/dental-image.jpg");
  background-position: left 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align:justify;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 950px;
  clear:both;
  min-height:870px;
}
#page-outline-dental-txt {
  height: 0px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 625px;
  float:left;
  text-align:justify;
}
#page-outline-dental-img {
  height: 0px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width:300px;
  float:right;
}
#page-outline-home {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/page-content-outline.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
width: 900px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: -5px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
height: 350px;
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
line-height:24px;
}
#page-outline-conact {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bg_team.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top;
width: 957px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 660px;
}
#page-outline-conact h2, #page-outline-contactthank h2 {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/contact-heading-one.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
height: 55px;
width: 700px;
text-indent: -9999px;
display: block;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 40px;
}
#page-outline-terms {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/terms-image.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
width: 900px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;
  line-height:22px;
}
#page-outline-terms h2 {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/terms-heading-one.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
height: 55px;
width: 411px;
text-indent: -9999px;
display: block;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 150px;
}
#page-outline-policy {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/policy-image.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
width: 900px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
line-height:22px;
padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;
}
#page-outline-policy h2 {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/policy-heading-one.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
height: 55px;
width: 500px;
text-indent: -9999px;
display: block;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 120px;
}
#page-outline-sitemap h2 {
background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/sitemap-heading-one.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
height: 55px;
width: 500px;
text-indent: -9999px;
display: block;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 120px;
}
#formgrid table {
margin:10px;
width:55%;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
#formgrid tr td {
padding:5px 5px;
}
#formgrid tr td input {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 3px;
}
#formgrid tr td textarea {
width: 99%;
background-color: #E5E5E5;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
padding: 3px;
margin-top: 5px;
  height:65px;
}
input[type="submit"]{ width:80px; height:30px; cursor:pointer;}

#bucketlist{
    border-left: 1px solid #5b8492;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-left:20px;
  width:365px;
}
#strong-bucket {
    background-image:url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/icon-strong.jpg");
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#strong-bucket h3, #build-bucket h3, #save-bucket h3 {
    padding:0 0 0 54px;
}
#strong-bucket p, #build-bucket p, #save-bucket p {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:120%;
    color: #666;
    padding: 0 16px 0px 58px;
}

#build-bucket {
    background-image:url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/icon-traffic.jpg");
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#save-bucket {
    background-image:url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/icon-time.jpg");
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}



/* Comments */

#comments h3 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal;padding: 10px 0 20px 0;}

#comments #comments_wrap {padding: 0; position: relative; }
#comments ol.commentlist li { list-style-type:none; }

#comments .comment { margin-top: 10px; width: 100%; }
#comments .comment a { text-decoration: underline; }
#comments .comment a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
#comments .comment small { font-size: 10px; margin-top: -2px; }

#comments .comment .col-left {width: 110px; font-size:11px;}
#comments .comment .col-left p { padding: 0 0 0 2px; line-height: 19px;}
#comments .comment .col-left .inside {
    width: 110px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height:70px;
}

#comments .comment .col-right {
    min-height: 92px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-left:100px;
    float:none; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;

}

* html #comments .comment .col-right { height: 100px; }
#comments .comment div.reply { float:right; padding: 3px 3px 0; font-size:11px; }
#comments .comment div.reply a { text-decoration:none; color:#aaa; }

#comments ul.children { margin:10px 0 0 25px; padding:0; }

#comments .navigation .alignright, #comments .navigation .alignleft { margin:10px 0;}
#comments .navigation a {
    color: #555;
}
#comments .commentlist {padding:0;}
#comments .commentlist p{padding:0 0 10px;}

#comments .commentlist #respond #form_wrap {
    padding:0 0 25px;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    width:auto;
}
#comments .commentlist .children #respond #form_wrap .col-right{float:none;}
#comments .cancel-comment-reply {margin-bottom:10px;}

#commentform .btn {
    margin:0; 
    background:url(images/btn-submit.png) no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:79px;
    height:41px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* (widgets)*/

#tag_cloud h2 {display: block;float: none;}
.textwidget {clear: both;padding: 5px 2px;line-height:20px;}
#wp-calendar {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    clear: both;
}
#wp-calendar caption {padding: 10px;}
#wp-calendar th {color: #fff;}
#wp-calendar th, #wp-calendar td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #E7E7E7;
    color: #9E9E9E;
}
#wp-calendar td {background: transparent;}
#wp-calendar td, table#wp-calendar th {padding: 3px 0;}
#wp-calendar a {text-decoration: underline;}
#wp-calendar a:hover {text-decoration: none;}

/* (flickr) */

#flickr .flickr_badge_image  { float: left; }

#flickr h3 span {color: #0061D8;}
#flickr h3 span span {color: #FF1183;}
#flickr .wrap {
    margin-left: -5px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
#flickr a img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    border: #CECFC6 1px solid;
}
#flickr a:hover img {border: #A8AA99 1px solid;}


/* Footer */

/*#footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #777;
} */
#footer {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url("http://www.dentalspaceadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/footer.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  color: #5B8492;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 59px;
  margin: 0px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#footer-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 7%;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 0px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div#footer-nav li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

div#footer-nav ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #5b8492;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-left: 1px solid #5b8492;
    height: 32px;
}

div#footer-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #999999;
}

div#footer-nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: none;
}
#footer a{ color:#0d1261; }
#footer .col-right img {vertical-align: middle;}
#footer .col-right span {display: none;}


/* Gravity forms */

.gfield { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.gform_wrapper .top_label .gfield_label { display:block; padding-right:20px; width: 100px; margin: 5px 0px 4px !important; }
.gform_wrapper input.button { background: url(images/btn-submit.png) no-repeat; border: 0px !important; color: white !important; font-weight: bold; height: 41px; width: 79px; margin: 0px 50px 0px 20px !important; }
.gform_wrapper input { padding: 7px 3px !important; }
.gform_wrapper .top_label input.large, .gform_wrapper .top_label select.large, .gform_wrapper .top_label textarea.textarea { width: 400px !important; padding: 7px 3px !important; }
.gform_wrapper .entry img, .gform_wrapper img.thumbnail { padding: 0px !important; border: 0px !important; }
ul.top_label .clear-multi { clear: none !important; }
.gform_wrapper .gfield_checkbox, .gform_wrapper .gfield_radio { margin-left: 70px !important; }
img.ui-datepicker-trigger { border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Comment: do you want a fixed footer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to keep your questions self consistent and don't just link stuff in your answer, please include the relevant explanations and code in your answer; so it is not reliant on external resources ;) BECAUSE, as soon as you got this fixed on your site, this question becomes useless to future readers.

Comment: Good point. I'll add the original code to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below to #footer in styles.css:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

or add this to wrap class: `overflow-y:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You could add `overflow: hidden;` to `#content` :

```
#content {
  background: #fff url(images/bg-content.png) repeat-y right;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 550px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these two two your footer css

```
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 71%;
```

[image]

for fixed footer and for scrolable footer

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

[image]